# solving a system with metric tensor components

Tags: tensors, general-relativity

Here is the energy and angular momentum for the Schwarzschild metric, a spherically symmetric spacetime in General Relativity.

$E=-u_{t}=-g_{ta}u^{a}=-g_{tt}u^t-g_{t\phi}u^{\phi}$

$L=u_{\phi}=g_{\phi a}u^{a}=g_{\phi t}u^t+g_{\phi\phi}u^{\phi}$

I want to solve this system for  $u^t$ and $u^{\phi}$.But I dont know how to "leave" $u^t$ and $u^{\phi}$ alone. All $g_{\alpha\beta}$ are the metric components of this spacetime.

I tried to multiply the first equation with $g^{ta}$  to eliminate $g_{tt}$ from $g_{tt}u^{t}$ :

$g^{ta}E=-g^{ta}g_{tt}u^{t}-g^{ta}g_{t\phi}u^{\phi}=-\delta^{a}_{t}u^t-\delta^{a}_{\phi}u^{\phi}=-2u^{a}=g^{at}E$

and then i change $a$ with $t$ because $a$ is a dummy index so i get :
$-2u^t=g^{tt}E$ --->$u^t=1/2*g^{tt}E$.
But that it is not the solution.

Edit: E and L expressions come from an axisymmetric spacetime.That is why there are mixed metric indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an ordinary linear system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
-g_{tt}u^t-g_{t\phi}u^{\phi} = E \\
g_{\phi t}u^t+g_{\phi\phi}u^{\phi} = L
\end{cases}$$
or in matrix form:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-g_{tt} & -g_{t\phi} \\
g_{\phi t} & g_{\phi\phi}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u^t \\
u^\phi
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
E \\
L
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The solution is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
u^t \\
u^\phi
\end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{-g_{tt}g_{\phi\phi}+g_{\phi t}g_{t\phi}}
\begin{pmatrix}
g_{\phi\phi} & g_{t\phi} \\
-g_{\phi t} & -g_{tt}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
E \\
L
\end{pmatrix}
$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
u^t = (g_{\phi\phi} E + g_{t\phi} L)/(g_{\phi t} g_{t \phi} - g_{tt} g_{\phi\phi}) \\
u^\phi = (-g_{\phi t} E - g_{tt} L)/(g_{\phi t} g_{t \phi} - g_{tt} g_{\phi\phi}) 
\end{cases}$$